# Can a blow to the head make a person learn something or given them a higher aptitude for learning something?

Tags: medical-science

I have heard stories about people acquiring skills after being hit in the head, [here is one of them](http://news.nationalpost.com/2014/04/23/from-head-injury-to-math-genius-on-savant-syndrome-and-the-possibility-of-a-little-rain-man-within-us-all/). In this particular story the man was assaulted and knocked unconscious and after he awoke he could see lines emanating from some objects. My understanding of the story is that to understand these lines he rigorously studied math. I found some parts of the story misleading as it implied the blow to the head is what caused his heightened mathematically ability.

Have there been any studies done to prove or disprove that people can actually learn something or acquire a new skill or improve upon knowledge they already know by receiving a blow to the head?

I'm not asking about cases where someone concisely decides to make an effort to learn something after a harrowing experience.

Comment: This story has a pretty flimsy premise: he got knocked on the head, then became interested in maths and *studied*. Perhaps we could redirect the question to ask whether "acquired savant syndrome" is a thing (whatever that means), as claimed by [Treffert](http://articles.philly.com/2012-08-20/news/33273378_1_brain-injury-owens-answers-car-crash).

Comment: Your title asks about being "smarter"; your post asks about "acquiring skills"; your example is claiming an "altered state of perception"; and the tags note "iq". Your final sentence seems to focus on acquiring skills which makes me think *that*'s what you really care about. Is it okay if we edit your question title to match?

Comment: @MrHen/Celeritas: I am concerned about stories that conclude "Since the accident in which I almost died, I've learnt to stop and smell the roses, not to take life for granted, and to take up painting." A person may acquire skills *after* an accident as a direct result of experiencing the accident, without it being some neurological phenomena. The example cited in the question doesn't seem that much different to this.

Comment: @Oddthinking: I agree completely. My comment was mostly addressing how the question is being formed; not the validity of the question/example/claim.

Comment: Related: *[Post hoc ergo propter hoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_ergo_propter_hoc)*

Comment: Your recent edit says "I'm not asking about cases where someone concisely decides to make an effort to learn something...", but your example is of a guy who "to understand these lines [...] rigorously studied math".

Comment: @Articuno what is your question?

Comment: I don't have a question. I just wanted to point out that what you say you're not asking about is actually the case in the example you provided. Resolving that contradiction would improve the question.

Comment: You're right I'm not wondering about the case in my example. My point is a lot of the stories are misleading in the sense they first seem to claim that the accident actually caused the gain of knowledge. I'm wondering if there are any events where this really is the case.